# How to reload authorities on user update with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm doing an application with authentication by OpenID using Spring Security.
When user is logged-in, some authorities are loaded in his session.

I have User with full right which can modify authorities (revoke, add roles) of others users. My question is, how to change User session authorities dynamically ? (cannot use *SecurityContextHolder* because I want to change another User session).

Simple way : invalidate user session, but how to ?
Better way : refresh user session with new authorities, but how to ?

Answer (score 68):

If you need to dynamically update a logged in user's authorities (when these have changed, for whatever reason), without having to log out and log in of course, you just need to reset the `Authentication` object (security token) in the Spring `SecurityContextHolder`.

Example:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(auth.getAuthorities());
updatedAuthorities.add(...); //add your role here [e.g., new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_NEW_ROLE")]

Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), updatedAuthorities);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

Comment: Well, it almost worked for me. This "auth" variable is concerned the logged in user (that is, me). If I am logged in as "x" and I'd like to revoke "y" authorities, how do I get Authentication's object from that specific user?

Comment: This only works for the current user. How to achieve this for another user?

Comment: I am confused why this answer has so many upvotes: it doesn't fully answer the question which clearly states that it is necessary to change the data of another user.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks, help me a lot ! With `SessionRegistry`, I can use [getAllPrincipals()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html#getAllPrincipals%28%29) to compare the user to modify with the current active users in sessions. If a session exist, I can invalidate his session using : [expireNow()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionInformation.html#expireNow%28%29) (from `SessionInformation`) to force re-authentication.

But I don't understand the usefulness of `securityContextPersistenceFilter` ?

EDIT :

```
// user object = User currently updated
// invalidate user session
List<Object> loggedUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
for (Object principal : loggedUsers) {
    if(principal instanceof User) {
        final User loggedUser = (User) principal;
        if(user.getUsername().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())) {
            List<SessionInformation> sessionsInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false);
            if(null != sessionsInfo && sessionsInfo.size() > 0) {
                for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionsInfo) {
                    LOGGER.info("Exprire now :" + sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                    sessionInformation.expireNow();
                    sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                    // User is not forced to re-logging
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `securityContextPersistenceFilter` by default will put `SecurityContext` into `HttpSession` in servlet environment. As you already have out-of-the-box spring `SessionRegistry` you do not need to customize this filter.

Comment: I am in servlet environment, what is the usefulness of customizing securityContextPersistenceFilter ?

Comment: different cases possible, e.g. `HttpSession`s are disabled and you don't want thread-local storage. So you can use your own implementation of `securityContextRepository`. If `HttpSession` storage suit your needs, then there is no usefulness.

Comment: I am using the code above (see EDIT) to invalidate user session. But I have a problem, user is not forced to re-logging... I think that the SecurityContextHolder is not cleared for this User.

How can I perform that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring's `SessionRegistry` API. If it provides direct access to `HttpSession` then you can clear `SecurityContext` manually. Or you may use your own session registry implementation, like one in my answer.

Comment: `SecurityContext` is for current logged user, but if I want to logout anohter user, how can i use it (to invalidate his session) ?

Comment: `SecurityContext` for each user lies in each user's session, see details [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/3.0.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java#L138). If you can access other user's session through registry then you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 13):

If anybody is still looking into how to update the authorities of another user without forcing that user to re-authenticate, you can try to add an interceptor that reloads the authentication. This will make sure that your authorities are always updated.

However -- due to the extra interceptor, there will be some performance impacts (e.g. if you get your user roles from your database, it will be queried for every HTTP request).

```
@Component
public class VerifyAccessInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }
    
        User userFromDatabase = getUserFromDatabase(auth.getName());
        if (userFromDatabase != null) {
            // add whatever authorities you want here
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("...")); 
        }
    
        Authentication newAuth = null;
    
        if (auth.getClass() == OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class) {
            OAuth2User principal = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken)auth).getPrincipal();
            if (principal != null) {
                newAuth = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(principal, authorities,(((OAuth2AuthenticationToken)auth).getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId()));
            }
        }
    
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This specific implementation uses OAuth2 (`OAuth2AuthenticationToken`), but you can use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instead.

And now, to add your interceptor to the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private VerifyAccessInterceptor verifyAccessInterceptor;


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(verifyAccessInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

}
```

[I also made an article about this](https://twin.sh/articles/24/spring-security-reload-authorities-on-every-request).

Answer (score 8):

The key point - you should be able to access users `SecurityContext`s.

If you are in servlet environment and are using `HttpSession` as `securityContextRepository` in your `securityContextPersistenceFilter`, then it can be done with spring's `SessionRegistry`. To force the user to re-auth (it should be better than silent permissions revocation) invalidate his `HttpSession`. Don't forget to add `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you are using thread-local `securityContextRepository`, then you should add custom filter to `springSecurityFilterChain` to manage `SecurityContext`s registry. To do this you must the use plain-bean `springSecurityFilterChain` configuration (without `security` namespace shortcuts). With plain-bean config with custom filters you'll have full control on authentication and authorization.

Some links, they don't solve exactly your problem (no OpenID), but may be useful:

- [NIH session registry](https://github.com/alx3apps/spring-embedded-tomcat/tree/master/components/src/main/java/ru/concerteza/springtomcat/components/registry) for servlet environment
- [it's plain-bean spring config](https://github.com/alx3apps/spring-embedded-tomcat/blob/master/etomcat6-test/src/main/app-dirs/registrydir/conf/etomcat-test-ctx.xml) working example
- [real life plain-bean spring config for X.509 auth](https://github.com/alx3apps/spring-embedded-tomcat/blob/master/etomcat6-test/src/main/app-dirs/x509dir/conf/etomcat-test-ctx.xml), you may start with it and modify it to use OpenID instead of X.509.

Answer (score 5):

I have a very specific case of above, I use Redis to track user session with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session. Then when admin adds some Role to the user I find user session in Redis and replace `principal` and `authorities` and then save the session.

```
public void updateUserRoles(String username, Set<GrantedAuthority> newRoles) {
        if (sessionRepository instanceof FindByIndexNameSessionRepository) {
            Map<String, org.springframework.session.Session> map =
                    ((FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<org.springframework.session.Session>) sessionRepository)
                            .findByPrincipalName(username);
            for (org.springframework.session.Session session : map.values()) {
                if (!session.isExpired()) {
                    SecurityContext securityContext = session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
                    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
                    if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
                        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>(authentication.getAuthorities());
                        //1. Update of authorities
                        authorities.addAll(newRoles);
                        Object principalToUpdate = authentication.getPrincipal();
                        if (principalToUpdate instanceof User) {
                            //2. Update of principal: Your User probably extends UserDetails so call here method that update roles to allow
                            // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails.getAuthorities return updated 
                            // Set of GrantedAuthority
                            securityContext
                                    .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principalToUpdate, authentication
                                            .getCredentials(), authorities));
                            session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, securityContext);
                            sessionRepository.save(session);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Searched for days now!

Answer (score 1):

I use the answer gived by TwiN, but I create a control variable (users_to_update_roles) to reduce performance impacts.

```
@Component
public class RoleCheckInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
public static ArrayList<String> update_role = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
private IUser iuser;

public static Set<String> users_to_update_roles = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    try {

        CurrentUser current = (CurrentUser) auth.getPrincipal();

        String username = current.getUser().getUsername();
        if (users_to_update_roles.contains(username)) {
            updateRoles(auth, current);
            users_to_update_roles.remove(username);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {

}

private void updateRoles(Authentication auth, CurrentUser current) {
    User findOne = iuser.findOne(current.getUser().getUsername());
    List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : findOne.getRoles()) {
        updatedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(),
            updatedAuthorities);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
}
}
```

and in my controller, I add the user that have they role updated

```
    public ModelAndView roleSave(@PathVariable long numero_documento, Funcionario funcionario) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("funcionario/role");
    Set<Role> roles = funcionario.getPessoa().getUser().getRoles();
    funcionario = funcionarioService.funcionarioNumero_documento(numero_documento);
    funcionario.getPessoa().getUser().setRoles(roles);
    iUser.save(funcionario.getPessoa().getUser());
    RoleCheckInterceptor.users_to_update_roles.add(funcionario.getPessoa().getUser().getUsername());
    modelAndView.addObject("funcionario", funcionario);
    modelAndView.addObject("sucess", "Permissões modificadas");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, but there is a race condition on users_to_update_roles. Synchronizing on the Set (which should be a ConcurrentHashSet if accessed like this) would work, but introduces a different problem.

Comment: @RüdigerSchulz do you have a good solution / example code?

Comment: @RüdigerSchulz what if you use `ConcurrentHashMap` that maps username (or better user ID) to Long and put the value of `AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()` in it when you change, and instead of remove by ID in `preHandle` you use `removeIf(value -> value.equals(valueRetrievedAtTheStartOfPreHandle))`?

Answer (score 0):

code:

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY;

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SessionAuthorityManager {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

    public void updateAuthority(User user) {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.create(user);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Session> map = sessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(principal.getName());
        var sessions = map.values();
        for (var session: sessions) {
            if (session.isExpired()) continue;
            var context = session.<SecurityContext>getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
            if (context == null) continue;
            var token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(principal, null, principal.getAuthorities());
            context.setAuthentication(token);
            session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, context);
            //noinspection unchecked
            sessionRepository.save(session);
        }
    }
}
```