# Logout delete or disable user usng spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I develop web application using spring-security, but I need logout an user. 
For example:

1. 'user1' login in application
2. application administrator, disable or delete 'user1'
3. application logout 'user1'

How can I do it?

Best regard, HLicea

Comment: There is no way to access an user session from another session because of security reasons.

What you can do to achieve is to create an  [interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-)  to intercept the user request and there check the user status and then invalidate the session there.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring does not provide a feature to automatically logout a user** if that user is deleted. You have to manually check if a user still exists when the user performs an action.

---

## Solution

Maybe **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295556/spring-security-delete-user-session-still-active)** question (and the suggested solutions in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295610/1391131)) might help you.