# Spring security has SimpleGrantedAuthority but hasRole isn't working

Tags: spring-security

I have the following code...

```
 private static Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> 
 readAuthorities(DecodedJWT jwt) {
    ...
    return authorities;
 }
```

It shows an `Admin` role. However, when I try to access a site by...

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.antMatchers(ADMIN).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getRoleName())
    ....
}
// Role.ADMIN.getRoleName() == "Admin"
```

But when I go the the site requiring the admin permission I get a 403.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your Security class needs to extend 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter', also annotate it with '@Configuration' and '@EnableWebSecurity'.  It may be doing that but I can't tell with your samples.  When you remove the antMatchers role does it work?

Comment: It already does have the annotation

Comment: yes it does work if I remove that line and rely on just authentication

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, spring security automatically prepends "ROLE_" onto role security requirements for things like .hasRole() and @Secured. So, you have to prepend "ROLE_" onto the roles when you assign them to users. If this is confusing, let me know and I'll go into more depth with examples from my project, I've just been working on this project for the last 12 hours and don't have time right now.

Comment: If you want to check by granted authorities directly and not roles, the `hasAuthority` method can be used.